# Add TAB reference to ASP.NET button

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, jquery-ui-tabs

I need to navigate to the certain tab when button is clicked.

The button is

```
<asp:Button ID="ButtonFind" runat="server" Text="Buscar" CssClass="btn btn-primary" UseSubmitBehavior="true" OnClick="ButtonSearch_Click" />
```

**JavaScript**
// Javascript to enable link to tab

```
var url = document.location.toString();
if (url.match('#')) {
    $('.nav-tabs a[href="#' + url.split('#')[1] + '"]').tab('show');
} 

// Change hash for page-reload
$('.nav-tabs a').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
     window.location.hash = e.target.hash;
})
```

But somehow the method

```
protected void ButtonSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
 // Fill Grid code
}
```

is replaced with

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!IsPostBack)
  {
    // Fill Grid by default
  }
}
```

And finally the grid has no found data and has default data. That's a problem.

I have try to use this

```
 protected void ButtonSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
     // Fill Grid code
string url = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path) + "#AllWorkOrders";

Response.Redirect(url, true);

    }
```

but there is a

```
if (!IsPostBack)
  {
    // Fill Grid by default
  }
```

still ...

I mean I need somehow return user to the correct TAB but `Response.Redirect` establish some trouble...

Probably there is a way to add `#AllWorkOrders` part of `QueryString` to

```
<asp:Button ID="ButtonFind" runat="server" Text="Buscar" CssClass="btn btn-primary" UseSubmitBehavior="true" OnClick="ButtonSearch_Click" />
```

but I don't know how to do it.

Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution that was quite easy to implemenet hahahahaa

I completely forgot about `PostBackUrl` property!

So the code looks like this now

```
 <asp:Button ID="ButtonFind" runat="server" Text="Buscar" CssClass="btn btn-primary" UseSubmitBehavior="true"
PostBackUrl="~/MyPage.aspx#AllWorkOrders"     OnClick="ButtonSearch_Click" />
```